# append function of gsheet api (nodejs) adding data at weird places in the row

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-nodejs-client

My gsheet has more than 26columns and only 3 to 4 of them have headers (and unequally spaced too)
now for some reason the append function is adding values to the new row after the end of the previous row. (Say a row ended at FY1, the next row values gets added from FZ2)

my append function looks like this:

```
append({
        spreadsheetId,
        range: "Sheet1",
        valueInputOption: 'RAW',
        resource: { values: [values] },
    })
```

i need to add row values to corresponding headers in the sheet.

Edit:

1. example of sheet:

   | A | B | C | D | E | ... | FY | FZ | GA | GB |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   |  | h1 | h2 |  | h3 | ... |  | h4 |  |  |
2. whats happening:

   | A | B | C | D | E | ... | FX | FY | FZ | GA | GB |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   |  | h1 | h2 |  | h3 | ... |  | h4 |  |  |  |
   |  |  |  |  |  | ... |  | d1 | d2 | d3 | d4 |
3. expectation:

   | A | B | C | D | E | ... | FX | FY | FZ | GA | GB |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   |  | h1 | h2 |  | h3 | ... |  | h4 |  |  |  |
   |  | d1 | d2 |  | d3 | ... |  | d4 |  |  |  |
4. `value` passed in `append()`: `[d1, d2, d3, d4]`
   according to the values and specified range ("Sheet1"), i guess it     should have added d1 from beginning of row itself

Comment: Hey @Tanaike added examples in the edit.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating it. From your additional information, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful for your situation, I apologize. By the way, unfortunately, you don't show the language you are using. So, from your showing script, I guessed that your script might be Node.js. If my guess was not correct, I apologize. But, I think that the workflow of this method is the same with another language.

Answer (score 0):

About your current issue, this Google issue tracker might be in the same situation. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/258372019) In this case, how about the following modification?

In this modification, first, the last row is retrieved by "Method: spreadsheets.values.get". And, the values are put from the specific column using "Method: spreadsheets.values.update".

#### Modified script:

```js
const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
const values = ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"]; // This value is from your question.

const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth });
const { data } = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({ spreadsheetId, range: sheetName });
const row = data.values.length + 1;
await sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
  spreadsheetId,
  range: `'${sheetName}'!B${row}`,
  resource: { values: [values] },
  valueInputOption: "RAW",
});
```

- When this script is run, `values` are put from column "B" of the next row of the last row of "Sheet1".
- If you want to put the values from column "A", please modify `` range: `'${sheetName}'!B${row}`, `` to `` range: `'${sheetName}'!A${row}`, ``.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)